# Pass value obtained from EditText box to a TextView in the next screen

Tags: android, textview, android-edittext

I have two java classes, HelloAndroidActivity and GetTasks. I want to try to get the text from the Edit Text box from the first activity on clicking the button and get that value in the next activity GetTasks and display it in the text view. My code is as shown:

HelloAndroidActivity

```
Button save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.save);
    save.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick (View v) {

            Intent i = new Intent(HelloAndroidActivity.this, GetTasks.class);
            //i.setClass(HelloAndroidActivity.this, GetTasks.class);
            EditText taskname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.task_name);
            String task_name = taskname.getEditableText().toString();
            Log.d("Task Name", task_name + "");
            i.putExtra("taskname", task_name);
            startActivity(i);

        }
    });
```

GetTasks

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_page_layout);

    CharSequence task_name = (CharSequence) findViewById(R.id.task_name);
    Log.d("Here", task_name + "");

    Intent i2 = getIntent();
    taskname = i2.getStringExtra("taskname");

    TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.gettaskname);
    text.setText(taskname);


}
```

Can you tell me what am I doing wrong? My application force closes itself. Instead of passing a variable, if I pass a string variable, I am able to see that in the text view? Does it have to do with the manifest file? I have an intent for both the activities. Any help regarding this would appreciated.

Comment: Which line causes the force close?

Comment: Please post a stack trace from your log. And use a comment or something to highlight which line of code is causing the exception to be thrown. It may also be helpful if you post your manifest file if you think that the problem might be in there.

Comment: What view type is `task_name`? Why do you cast it to `CharSequence`?

Answer (score 2):

I believe that the line

`CharSequence task_name = (CharSequence) findViewById(R.id.task_name);`

is the most likely culprit. `CharSequence` should replaced with whatever type of a view the task_name element is...

Comment: Here is the stack trace:

    11-15 20:19:00.298: E/AndroidRuntime(279): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-15 20:19:00.298: E/AndroidRuntime(279): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView
11-15 20:19:00.298: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at com.example.helloandroid.HelloAndroidActivity$3.onClick(HelloAndroidActivity.java:67)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `(CharSequence)`, use `(EditText)`, that is the type of layout object your are retrieving the data from, as defined your layout XML file.

---

In your `GetTasks.onCreate` method, you need to bring in the values that you passed from the intent in the `HelloAndroidActivity`.

You do that like this:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras ==null) { return;} 
String taskname = extras.getString("taskname");
```

See the following link for a [good tutorial on using intents](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidIntent/article.html)